# Configuration of the SDN network

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming, openflow, pox, sdn

How can I configure network with a python written file through a SDN controller (POX,Ryu). What file which would run in a SDN controller TO configure the links and IP addresses of  Open Flow switches and hosts?

I am able to configure flow tables only.

Answer (score 1):

**Method I:**

```
class ofp_action_nw_addr (object):
  @classmethod
  def set_dst (cls, nw_addr = None):
    return cls(OFPAT_SET_NW_DST, nw_addr)
  @classmethod
  def set_src (cls, nw_addr = None):
    return cls(OFPAT_SET_NW_SRC, nw_addr)

  def __init__ (self, type = None, nw_addr = None):
    self.type = type
    if nw_addr is not None:
      self.nw_addr = IPAddr(nw_addr)
    else:
      self.nw_addr = IPAddr(0)
```

**Method II**

Try to use Mininet and this tools:

[Mininet Apps](http://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Mininet-Apps)